# ASP.NET MVC3: Issue on working with dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm new with ASP.NET MVC and currently my company is implementing ASP.NET MVC. I'm struggling to implement dropdownlist. Here is the scenario: 
I have to make use of dropdownlist, textbox and a search button to get all queries.
I have a list of items to be listed on dropdown. When I select any of the item, then I have to  provide value mannually on textbox and have to search and populate all required information if exist.

For example: when I click dropdownlist, it may listed employee name, employee id, etc.. and if I select employee name from dropdownlist, then I have to provide name on textbox like, Marry Lieu then next I have to click search button. This button should check Marry Lieu's information and populate on the screen.

How to mapped between dropdownlist, textbox and button so that I could select certain property on dropdownlist, value of the property to be type in textbox, search the information and populate??

Any guidelines will matter a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use some javascript for this task. You can attach a change event to the select using JQuery. In this example (http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) attached function just gets the text for each selected option and writes them in the 'div', but you can make own function with some other logic such us getting info via POST query to mvc controller, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm being a bit cheeky here and reusing parts of Darin Dimitrov's answer:

The key difference is we're conditionally searching for employee based on the selected drop down value eg by-name of by-id

I'm just trying to illustrate how it could work at a basic level but I think in a proper implementation I'd not want to use string literals for the criteria list and instead have an object to represent the possible criteria for finding an employee.

**Search View** which contains criteria propeties

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    // property used to represent the selected employees search critera field
    [DisplayName("Search by")]
    public string SelectedCriteria { get; set; }

    // property used to hold the list of possible criteria shown in the dropdown
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Criteria { get; set; }

    // property used for the textbox 
    // ie the value to search against the criteria
    [DisplayName("Value")]
    public string CriteriaValue { get; set; }

    // property that will be populated after submitting the form
    // and contain the search results. I am using string for the
    // purpose of the demonstration but could be any arbitrary complex
    // view model depending on what your results contain
    public string SearchResult { get; set; }
}
```

**Home Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static List<string> CriteriaList
    {
        get 
        {
            return new List<string>() { "Employee Name", "Employee Id" };
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SearchViewModel
        {
            Criteria = CriteriaList.Select(e => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = e,
                Text = e
            })
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        // at this stage we have the Selected Criteria and Criteria Value
        // we find the employee based on this criteria:

        Employee employee = null;

        switch (model.SelectedCriteria)
        {
            case "Employee Name":
                employee = _employeeRepository.GetByName(model.CriteriaValue);
                break;
            case "Employee Id":
                employee = _employeeRepository.GetById(model.CriteriaValue);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (employee == null)
            model.SearchResult = "No results found for of your search";
        else
            model.SearchResult = string.Format("The Employee {0} was found",
                                               employee.Name);

        // we repopulate the criteria collection because only the selected
        // criteria was passed when the form was submitted
        model.Criteria = CriteriaList.Select(e => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = e,
            Text = e
        });

        // we redisplay the view
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**~/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@model SearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedCriteria)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedCriteria, 
            Model.Criteria,
            new { id = "employee-criteria" }
        )
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CriteriaValue)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CriteriaValue)
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}

<div id="results">
    @if (Model.SearchResult != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Result", Model.SearchResult)
    }
</div>
```

**~/Views/Home/_Result.cshtml** as Darin answer

```
@model string
<div>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a view model:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    // property used to represent the selected employee id in the dropdown
    [DisplayName("Employee")]
    public string SelectedEmployeeId { get; set; }

    // property used to hold the list of employees shown in the dropdown
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employees { get; set; }

    // property used for the textbox
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    // property that will be populated after submitting the form
    // and contain the search results. I am using string for the
    // purpose of the demonstration but could be any arbitrary complex
    // view model depending on what your results contain
    public string SearchResult { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SearchViewModel
        {
            Employees = db.Employees.ToList().Select(e => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = e.EmployeeId,
                Text = e.Name
            })
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        // at this stage we have the SelectedEmployeeId and SomeValue
        // properties passed => we do the search and set the results:

        model.SearchResult = "this is the result of your search";

        // we repopulate the Employees collection because only the selected
        // employee id was passed when the form was submitted
        model.Employees = db.Employees.ToList().Select(e => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = e.EmployeeId,
            Text = e.Name
        });

        // we redisplay the view
        return View(model);
    } 
}
```

Next we could have a `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model SearchViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedEmployeeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.SelectedEmployeeId, 
            Model.Employees, 
            new { id = "employeesDdl" }
        )
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EmployeeName)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EmployeeName)
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}

<div id="results">
    @if (Model.SearchResult != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Result", Model.SearchResult)
    }
</div>
```

Next we define a `~/Views/Home/_Result.cshtml` partial that will display the results of the search:

```
@model string
<div>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</div>
```

Then if you want to display the selected employee name in the textbox when the dropdownlist selection changes you could use jQuery and subscribe to the `.change()` event of this dropdown. So in a separate javascript we could put the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#employeesDdl').change(function() {
        var employeeName = $('option:selected', this).text();
        $('#EmployeeName').val(employeeName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm miss reading your solution but I think the OP is looking to change the search criteria based on the dropdownlists selected item. ie The dropdown label would be "Search by:" e.g. the dropdownlist would contain the string literals "EmployeeName", "EmployeeId". Then the user should input "Mary" if EmployeeName selected or input "0099" if EmployeeId selected.

Comment: @mouters, maybe you are correct. I probably didn't understand what the OP is asking.